# LibGDX TextButton - Any event getting called repeatedly as long as it's held down?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am making a game where you have two buttons to rotate the player, one to left and the other one to right. I'm using a `TextButton` in `LibGDX`. My problem is that the method `clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)` in `ClickListener` is only called once it's clicked. I want an event to be called repeatedly as long as it's held down. Here is my code:

```
TextButton btnLeft = new TextButton("<", styleButton);
TextButton btnRight = new TextButton(">", styleButton);

btnLeft.setSize(100, 100);
btnRight.setSize(100, 100);

btnLeft.setPosition(25, 25);
btnRight.setPosition(200, 25);

btnLeft.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        player.rotate(-1);
        System.out.println("Left");
    }
});
btnRight.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        player.rotate(1);
        System.out.println("Right");
    }
});

stage.addActor(btnLeft);
stage.addActor(btnRight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener is not good place to perform continuous actions since it is by definition asynchronous mechanism. The place to perform some action like this is **render()** method of Screen or **act()** method of actor.

Although you can use listener to check a state of actor (is it pressed or not) in this way:

```
//Global instance
ClickListener listenerLeft;

//show() method
...
listenerLeft= new ClickListener();  
btnLeft.addListener(listenerLeft);
...

//render() method
...
if(listenerLeft.isPressed())
    //perform turning left
...
```

The second option is to implement [ClickListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html)'s **touchUp** and **touchDown** methods to change some flag and then check it in **render** but it would not be doing anything new.

---

Worth to notice is than both ClickListener and DragListener have **touchDragged** method that is something about what you want but works only **if the mouse/finger is moving when touching actor**

```
listener = new DragListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
            System.out.println("Left");
        }
    };
```

Keeping touching is not an action - no action = nothing to listen